# Template Class C++ - exclude some types

Tags: c++, templates, types

i recently created a template class which is working fine.

Now i wanted to use "const int" (for example), but dynamic binding is forbidden.

is there a possibility to exclude the type const int?

this is my class; the compiler will drop out an error for the 2nd constructor. i've seen that one coming, but i just don't know how to modify it the correct way - and ideas?

```
template <class T>
class Vector2D
{
public:
    T X;
    T Y;

    Vector2D()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
    };

    Vector2D(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    };
}
```

Comment: You can handle qualifiers like `const` via overloads and/or type traits. If you want to cause a compiler error when callers use the `const` qualifier in the argument then use `static_assert` in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use member initialization lists:

```
template <class T>
class Vector2D
{
public:
    T X;
    T Y;

    Vector2D(): X(0), Y(0)
    {
    };

    Vector2D(T x, T y):X(x),Y(y)
    {
    };
}
```

That should solve your current problem with `const int`. If you're really interested in forbidding a certain type in general, take a look at [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `type_traits` and `static_assert` to prevent instantiation of your class using a `const` type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class Vector2D
{
  static_assert( !std::is_const<T>::value, "T must be non-const" );
    T X;
    T Y;

public:
    Vector2D() : X( 0 ), Y( 0 )
    {
    }

    Vector2D(T x, T y) : X( x ), Y( y )
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
  Vector2D<int> v1( 10, 20 );
  Vector2D<const int> v2( 10, 20 ); //static_assert fails
}
```

Also, I've changed your class to use member initialization lists in the constructor to initialize member variables. And I've made `x` and `y` `private`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what 'Concept Checking' is for.

Check out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm

(GCC 4.7 implements it in std:: though, because it is likely to be added in a future standard.)